# How to get the minute difference between two Carbon objects ignoring the date?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a start date

```php
$start = Carbon::parse('2023-03-01 10:00:00');
```

and an end date

```php
$end = Carbon::parse('2023-03-02 17:00:00');
```

I want to get the minutes between `10:00:00` and `17:00:00` ignoring the date.

I made this working with

```php
$time_end = $end->toTimeString();
$time_start = $start->toTimeString();
$duration = Carbon::parse($time_end)->diffInMinutes(Carbon::parse($time_start));
```

but with the `toTimeString()` I kind of leaving the Carbon object and I feel there must be a better approach.

Even if I don't find a function like that in the `CarbonInterface` I still feel this must be accomplished better.

Another idea I had is:

```php
$duration = $end->diffInMinutes($start) - 24 * 60  * $end->diffInDays($start);
```

Comment: What if the time on the second date is less than the first?  Is this a -ve value or should it always be +ve;

Comment: end is always after start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon has a setDateFrom(DateTime Object) method. The method only takes the date from the argument. The time remains unchanged. The above task can be solved with one line of code as follows:

```
$duration = $start->setDateFrom($end)->diffInMinutes($end);
```

Comment: Your codes works even I don't understand your comment  You talk about `getDateFrom()` but provide `setDateFrom()`. If the function takes the date, I don't understand why this works. But it works :D

Comment: That was a typo. setDateFrom is correct. For your example dates start: '2023-03-01 10:00:00' and end:'2023-03-02 17:00:00' after setDateFrom($end) the object has this date : '2023-03-02 10:00:00'. Year, month and Day from end, time from start.

Answer (score 0):

First note that:

```php
$duration = Carbon::parse($time_end)->diffInMinutes(Carbon::parse($time_start));
```

As code is not instantly executed, the second `Carbon::parse()` might happen few microseconds after the first one and this might be 23:59.999 and then 00:00.000 so on a different date.

So you better keep the date from start and refer to end time:

```php
$time_start = $start->toTimeString();
$startTimeWithEndDate = $end->copy()->modify($time_start);
$duration = $end->diffInMinutes($startTimeWithEndDate);
```

Then here you can (if you need) swap the difference if end time is lower then start time:

```php
$time_start = $start->toTimeString();
$startTimeWithEndDate = $end->copy()->modify($time_start);

if ($startTimeWithEndDate > $end) {
    $startTimeWithEndDate->addDay();
}

$duration = $end->diffInMinutes($startTimeWithEndDate);
```